# Count id in Data Extension and Upsert to another Data Extension using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

This question might be a basic one but I am very new to SSJS so thank you for your understanding.

The data extension names JourneyA, JourneyB, JourneyC...infinity are the result of Journey Builder. Then, I got the data extension name AllJourneys from _Journey.

```
SELECT JourneyName as "JourneyName",
FROM _Journey j
INNER JOIN(select JourneyID, max(CreatedDate) as MaxDate FROM _Journey
GROUP BY JourneyID) sort on sort.JourneyID = j.JourneyID and j.CreatedDate = sort.MaxDate
```

After that, I would like to count the number of audiences in each journey and put the results in the data extension name Summary using upsert. Additionally, the data extension name Summary is a non-sendable data extension.

[image]

According to my understanding, the data extension name Summary can be done by SSJS (Script Activity in Automation Studio), right? or please suggest me if it can be done in any other way.

I have done some SSJS but cannot figure out what I should do next.

```
<script runat="server">  
Platform.Load("core","1"); 

  var AllJourneys = DataExtension.Init('AllJourneys');
  var AllJourneysData = AllJourneys.Rows.Retrieve();
  
  var Summary = DataExtension.Init('Summary');

  for (var i = 0; i < testDEData.length; i++) {
      var eachJourney = DataExtension.Init('eachJourney');
      var eachJourneyData = eachJourney.Rows.Retrieve();

      var JourneyName = AllJourneysData[i].JourneyName;
      var count = xxx
      var result = Summary.Rows.Upsert({"JourneyName":JourneyName}, ['Count(CusID)'], [count]);
  }
</script>
```